# Home directory does not mount on kernel update

Tags: networking, kernel, mount

My home directory will not mount on booting with new linux kernel. Previously, my home directory has been mounted automatically from a network device. I updated my kernel to 4.6.0 from the git repository and now, after re-booting the new kernel, the home directory is not mounted. How should I fix this problem? Is there any configuration parameter that I missed to set while compiling the kernel? 
**UPDATE:**
How can I pass parameter to new kernel. Permanent or so on.

Comment: could you please post kernel logs, error message ?

Comment: Can you mount SMB and NFS shares as root from the Command Line?  If this errors out also check your kernel config(my hunch is that it will not succeed), specifically `Filesystems-->Network Filesystems`.  Compile them as built-in, i.e. the `*`.  My hunch is that you missed them.